# I have disabled multi touch but still not working unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have disabled multitouch but still, when I place second finger on the screen my joystick snaps to the second finger position.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

I am using variable joystick from free joystick pack.

Comment: You need to change your joystick code to only listen to the first touch: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html

Comment: Actually here was that i was testing on the unity remote app and that app doesn't turn off the multi touch option even if we set the Input.multiTouchEnabled to false.

So I created a build and tested it and seems like this works fine as the way I expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

That would work only if the app was **installed** on the device, it will not work on the editor and not even using Unity remote, since Unity remote streams your game only and passes some parameters while streaming.

For more info about Unity Remote: [Unity Manual - Unity Remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/UnityRemote5.html)